# how do escape string replacement function in bash in xargs?

Tags: bash

I was trying to use bash's string replace function in xargs. But I keep getting bad substitution errors.
The command I tried to use:

```
ls / | xargs -I{} sh -c 'x={};echo ${x/something/somethingelse}'
```

I could do it with sed, but I cannot figure out what's the problem with the above command.

Error message:
sh: 1: Bad substitution

---

As KamilCuk has stated below, this was mostly due to using dash as /bin/sh.

Comment: `in xargs` then post what have you tried _with xargs_. The code that you posted works fine. `I keep getting bad substitution errors` Please post the verbatim error message.

Comment: Edited. Please take a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

- `${var/a/b}` expansion is a Bash feature, which may be not available on other shells (most notably `dash`).
- Do not parse ls. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead
- `'x={};` the `{}` part is getting interpreted by the shell, according to shell gramma rules.
- `xargs` by default interprets `"` `'` `\` in input strings.

Remedies:

- Call Bash explicitly if you intent to use Bash features.
- Do not use `ls`. (Or ignore best practice)
- Do no use `{}` inside `-c` scripts. Use arguments. Remember to quote argument expansions.
- Explicitly specify delimiter for `xargs`.

For example:

```
printf "%s\n" /* | xargs -d '\n' -n1 bash -c 'x="$1"; echo ${x/something/somethingelse}' --
printf "%s\n" /* | xargs -d '\n' -I{} bash -c 'x="$1"; echo ${x/something/somethingelse}' -- {}
find / -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | xargs -d '\n' -n1 bash -c 'x="$1"; echo ${x/something/somethingelse}' --
find / -mindepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 bash -c 'x="$1"; echo ${x/something/somethingelse}' --
```

Comment: I've tried your commands but I'm still getting "--: 1: Bad substitution" error. I'm using WSL ubuntu. Does that have anything to do with this issue?

Comment: Och - I know I know.

Comment: Edited - added Bash. Could be that your `sh` is dash or ash? What distribution are you running? I see on ubuntu with dash `${//}` is not supported.

Comment: Yes it looks like it's being linked to dash.